# C# - Impersonation Issue: Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid

Tags: c#, impersonation

Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated.

I have a console app which runs on users PCs. Within the app I want to impersonate an admin account so I can writes files to the users `C:\Program Files` folder.

When I attempt this I receive the error **"Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid"**

I'm using the `LogonUser` impersonation method where I specify the domain, username & password parameters along with the following:

```
LogonType set to: const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
LogonProvider set to: const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
```

Does anyone know the LogonType & LogonProvider values I must specify to allow me to achieve this?

I have verified that the Admin account I'm using can write to the users `C:\Program Files` folder so I'm guessing this should be achievable via code also

Comment: Try running your app as an admin. If that works, then there's your issue. Your other solution would be to not write at that location, but to the user's Documents folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply krillgar. The issue is that I want the app to run at statrtup. By using impersonation I though I could temporarily impersonate an admin user just to allow me to perform the file copy... all within the console app

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's not allowed with the new UAT guidelines they initiated with Windows Vista. Otherwise, every virus out there would be doing that and have full control over the system. Like I said originally, using a different folder would probably be your best solution.

Comment: Yes - but I'm specifying the username, password and domain details of the admin account which I am impersonating. What I'm doing is part of a wider project so unfortunately I have to write to the users "C:\Program Files". I have no alternative unfortunately.

Comment: @P_Fitz were you able to find a solution to this issue?